# If $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is continuous at a point $z_0$, then show that $\overline {f(\bar z)}$ is also continuous at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

If $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is continuous at a point $z_0$, then show that $\overline {f(\bar z)}$ is also continuous at $z_0$. Is the same true for the differentiability at $z_0$?

I'm trying to formulate a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof for this. Since $\overline {f(z)}$ is continuous at $z_0$, it suffices to show that $f(\bar z)$ is continuous at $z_0$. This is where I'm having a problem.

I need to show that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is some $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|z-z_0|\lt \delta$ then $|f(\bar z)-f(\bar z_0)| \lt \epsilon$. However, my attempts have so far failed. How can I show this? Also for the differentiability part, my guess is it is not true. What kind of counterexamples are there? I would appreciate any solutions or hints to these questions.

Comment: Should it be "is also continuous at $\bar z_0$"? Otherwise it should be false.

Comment: @gerw Oh it's a problem from a book I'm looking at but if it meant $\bar z_0$ then it doesnt really mean anything...Are you sure it is false?

Comment: I think so. You can take any function $f$ which has exactly one (non-real) point of discontinuity, which you call $\bar z_0$.

Answer (score 3):

So I think the right statement is:

If $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ is continuous at $z_0$, then the function $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is continuous at $\overline{z_0}$.

The statement that you gave is false, you can consider the function $f(z)=0$ if $z \neq -i$ and $f(-i)=1$.

To prove the statement above, I think you should be thinking in terms of limits. A function is continuous at a point $z_0$ if $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)-f(z_0)=0.$

Then you have $$\lim_{\overline{z} \to \overline{z_0}} \overline{f(z)} - \overline{f(z_0)} =\overline{\lim_{\overline{z} \to \overline{z_0}} f(z)-f(z_0)}=0. $$
Hence you have the continuity of your function at $\overline{z_0}$.

Comment: The example you gave is not continuous at $z_0$, isn't it?

Comment: For the differentiability part, you should give an argument similar to that one using the following the fact that $\overline{z}*\overline{w}=\overline{z*w}$ and if your function is differentiable, that $f'(z_0)= lim_{z \to z_0} \dfrac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$

Comment: You were right, so now you have a function that is continuous at $i$, but your new function is not continuous at $i$